# Overloading Operator output

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Hi all I'm fairly new to c++ though I have some knowledge of Java basics.

I have this operator<<:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Rational& r) {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;

    b = r.n_;
    c = r.d_;
    if (c >= b) {
        a = (b / c);
        d = (b % c);

        r.n_ = d;}


    return out << r.n_ << '/' << r.d_;
    }
```

Basically what I am trying to do is; if the fraction I want to output is a improper fraction, I want to be able to convert it to a mixed number format before outputting it. I have wrote the if statement to calculate the mixed number but I'm having trouble figuring out how to output it using the << operator as it can only take two parameters. If there is a way to do it (without editing the class instance variables.).

(The Rational class has two instance variables Numerator and Denominator)

Any help or ideas will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance. ^^

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you want `if (c <= b)`, right?

Comment: I don't really understand the question, but it seems counter intuitive to have an output stream operator that modifies its second operand.

Comment: you cant output mixed fraction like that because there is no such thing in computers. you could make them look like that but its tedious in c++ and just a visual appearance.

Comment: you could print like this `return out << a << "(" << r.n_ << '/' << r.d_ << ")\n";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really understand what you mean by 'the `<<` operator can only take two parameters'.  It looks like you're trying to do something like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Rational& r)
{
    if (r.n_ > r.d_)
    {
        int whole = r.n_ / r.d_;
        int numerator = r.n_ % r.d_;
        return out << whole << ' ' << numerator << '/' << r.d_;
    }

    return out << r.n_ << '/' << r.d_;
}
```

Which seems pretty straightforward, I think.  Maybe I'm missing something about your question?

Comment: No you're not. That's what I wanted, Clearly, I make things more difficult than I need to for myself. Thanks a lot though, appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, happy to help.  I just wasn't sure if I was reading your question correctly.